# Can't play a blob-url video using Chrome for Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, video

I'm facing an unusual issue while trying to record and play a video in Chrome for Android. (Same code works fine on Chrome for Desktop).

First of all, some informations:

- Android 4.4.2
- Chrome for Android 40.0.2214.89
- It works on Chrome for Desktop 40.0.2214.94 m
- After storing blob on a local file, it's correctly reproduced by the mediaplayer-app.
- Required RecordRTC.js

My goal is that to record a video from tablet's camera and than play the recorded video.
Here's an example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Camera Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.WebRTC-Experiment.com/RecordRTC.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

<script>


var cameraStream;
var cameraEl;
var cameraRecorder;
var cameraBlobURL;

window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL; 
navigator.getUserMedia = (  navigator.getUserMedia ||
                            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                            navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                            navigator.msGetUserMedia);



function askForCamera(){
    navigator.getUserMedia(
        { 
            video : true 
        },
        function(stream) {
            cameraStream = stream;
            cameraEl = document.getElementById("vidCamera");
            cameraEl.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);  
        },
        function(){
            alert('fail camera');
        }
    );
}


function playCamera(){
    cameraEl.play();
}


function startRec(){
    cameraRecorder = RecordRTC(
                    cameraStream, 
                    {
                        type: 'video',
                        disableLogs : true
                    }
    );              
    cameraRecorder.startRecording();            
}

function stopRec(){
    cameraRecorder.stopRecording(function(blobURL){
        cameraBlobURL = blobURL;
        console.log(cameraBlobURL);
        alert(cameraRecorder.getBlob().type + '     ' +cameraRecorder.getBlob().size);

    });
}

function setBlob(){
    cameraEl.src = cameraBlobURL;   
}


</script>


<p>Buttons:</p>
<button type="button" onclick="askForCamera()">Ask for camera</button>
<button type="button" onclick="playCamera()">Play camera</button>
<button type="button" onclick="startRec()">Start Rec</button>
<button type="button" onclick="stopRec()">Stop Rec</button>

<button type="button" onclick="setBlob()">Set blob to camera</button>
<button type="button" onclick="playCamera()">Play camera</button>

<br/>
<p>Camera:</p>
<video id="vidCamera" width="200" height="200">
</video>



    </body>
</html>
```

How should I proceed in order to make sure it works on Chrome for Android?
Hope someone can help me.
Thanks to all!

Comment: Have you managed to work it out eventually?

Comment: @Shay: Unfortunately, I didn't found any solution yet. I suppose, for some reason, that Chrome can't access his temporary files on filesystem.

Comment: What a shame, so there's no solution for running local videos on Android? This ruins everything. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've also run into this problem on Chrome 41 and believe its a bug. Possibly this issue:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=253465

Comment: yeah, definitely a bug in Android.  works fine for stylesheets, images, but the media module apparently resolves cache paths differently.  Works find on Chrome desktop, Safari, and iOS.