# Android webview video does not reach readyState=4

Tags: javascript, android, webview, html5-video, android-ffmpeg

I am auto-playing a video in an Android Webview.
This gives problem with slow internet connections. I get the ANR popup (Application not responding)

I think it happens because the video receives a video.play() before the data is loaded. After 5 seconds the ANR popup appears.

What i want to do to solve this, is to wait for the video to be fully loaded, before calling video.play()

The problem is that the video in the Webview doesn't receive video.readystate == 4. It does never reach further as readystate 2. Even at normal internet connections.
In my Chrome browser it does receive readystate 4. So why is this? Why does the video in the Webview not receive readystate 4?

Below my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Video</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="item" class="item">
            <video preload="auto" autobuffer width="1024" height="576" id="video">
                <source id="videomp4" src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
            </video>
            <script>
                var interval;
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    interval = setInterval('playVideoWhenReady()', 1000);       
                    /*
                    // this doesn't work either
                    video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
                        // Video is loaded and can be played
                        console.log("video play is triggered");
                        video.play();
                    }, false);
                    */
                });

                function playVideoWhenReady() {
                    var video = document.getElementById('video');
                    console.log("!!!!! curstate: " + video.readyState);
                    if ( video.readyState == 4 ) { // this is never true in Android Webview
                        video.play();
                        clearInterval(interval);
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

MainActivity:

```
package net.eyefinder.www.testvideo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        final WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/video.html");
    }
}
```

and this it the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.eyefinder.www.testvideo">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

Then the log output is:

```
10-31 10:55:37.369 2181-2195/net.myapp.www.testvideo D/MediaPlayerPrivateAndroid: load url=http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4
10-31 10:55:37.389 2181-2181/net.myapp.www.testvideo D/TilesManager: Starting TG #0, 0x67360d10
10-31 10:55:37.399 2181-2181/net.myapp.www.testvideo D/TilesManager: new EGLContext from framework: 63c6cd40 
10-31 10:55:37.399 2181-2181/net.myapp.www.testvideo D/GLWebViewState: Reinit shader
10-31 10:55:37.429 2181-2181/net.myapp.www.testvideo D/GLWebViewState: Reinit transferQueue
10-31 10:55:37.449 2181-2181/net.myapp.www.testvideo D/VideoLayerManager: Reinit GLResource for VideoLayer
10-31 10:55:38.439 2181-2181/net.myapp.www.testvideo I/Web Console: !!!!! curstate: 2 at ../video.html:23
10-31 10:55:39.379 2181-2181/net.myapp.www.testvideo I/Web Console: !!!!! curstate: 2 at ../video.html:23
10-31 10:55:40.379 2181-2181/net.myapp.www.testvideo I/Web Console: !!!!! curstate: 2 at ../video.html:23
```

And it keeps hanging in curstate 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research i came to the conclusion that there is no proper way to wait for a video before it is loaded fully in the Android Webview.

Of course, there are some solutions like:

```
<video preload="auto" autobuffer width="1024" height="576" id="video"></video>
<script>
    var interval;
    $(function () {
        var video = document.getElementById('video');

        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', 'http://your-video-url.mp4', true);
        req.responseType = 'blob';

        req.onload = function() {
            // Onload is triggered even on 404
            // so we need to check the status code
            if (this.status === 200) {
                var videoBlob = req.response;
                var vid = (window.URL || window.webkitURL || window || {}).createObjectURL(videoBlob); // IE10+
                // Video is now downloaded
                // and we can set it as source on the video element
                video.src = vid;
                video.load();
            }
        }
        req.onerror = function() {
            // Error
        }

        req.send();

        video.addEventListener('progress', function() {
            var range = 0;
            var bf = this.buffered;
            var time = this.currentTime;

            while(!(bf.start(range) <= time && time <= bf.end(range))) {
                range += 1;
            }
            var loadStartPercentage = bf.start(range) / this.duration;
            var loadEndPercentage = bf.end(range) / this.duration;
            var loadPercentage = loadEndPercentage - loadStartPercentage;

            console.log("time: " + time);
            console.log("loadStartPercentage: " + loadStartPercentage);
            console.log("loadEndPercentage: " + loadEndPercentage);
            console.log("loadPercentage: " + loadPercentage);

            if ( loadPercentage == 1 ) {
                 video.play();
            }
        });
    });
```

BUT this solution does NOT work on Android 4.2 (regarding to [Why can't my Android device play HTML5 video loaded as Blob via XHR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852298/why-cant-my-android-device-play-html5-video-loaded-as-blob-via-xhr)).

So i implemented a video downloader in Android and parse the local file URL to JavaScript. Now there is no need to wait for a video to be loaded.

My problem with slow connections is now solved!

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me with the following configuration :

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

final WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);

webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/video.html");
```

In `src/main/assets/video.html` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Video</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <video preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" autobuffer width="1024" height="576" id="video" />
    <script>
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    video.src = 'http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4';
    video.load();

    video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
        video.play();
    }, false);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And with Internet permission in manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Your code does not work for me. I can only auto play the video when i am using the WebChromeClient. How can you get this done without it? Can you please post your complete manifest file?

Comment: Did you add android:hardwareAccelerated="true" to your application manifest ? Otherwise the rest is quite basic

Comment: Yes i have. I just edited my question to give you more information.

Comment: Addiitonal info: When i call video.play() without interval. It reaches readystate  == 4. But i do not just want to play, i want to wait for the readyState == 4 before i do that.

Comment: If you look at my code. When i remove the setWebChromeClient() the video just does not load.

Comment: Which Android version are you using ?

Comment: Good question! 4.2.2

Comment: I have added an `eventListener` instead of  your `setInterval` and loaded the video in JS rather than inside the html, this way you can configure it easily. This is working for me on a 4.2 device, `WebChromeClient` is indeed necessary (it was working without it on an Android 6 device)

Comment: Thank you Bertrand. I do not have problems playing a video. My real problem is that i get an ANR when the video load time is more as 5 seconds. That is why i want to wait for a readyState == 4 before playing, to prevent the ANR from popping up. In the code you just posted, the readyState does not reach "4" too. But.. it is a different approach you suggested. And i will try that. Maybe it accidentaliy solves my problem. We'll see.

Comment: settings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false); saved my day!